# Ввод и вывод массива структур (Си)

Tags: c, структуры

Только осваиваю язык Си. Написал код для ввода и вывода массива стркуктур, но программа крашится после ввода первого значения. Почему данный код не работает. На С++ подобная схема срабатывала.

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct POINT
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

void input(struct POINT* saske, int n);
void output(struct POINT* saske, int n);

int main()
{
    struct POINT* saske;
    saske = (struct POINT*)malloc(2 * sizeof(struct POINT));
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 1;
    input(saske, n1);
    input(saske, n2);
    output(saske,n1);
    output(saske, n2);
    return 0;
}

void input(struct POINT* saske, int n)
{
    scanf_s("%lf", &saske[n].x);
    scanf_s("%lf", &saske[n].y);
}
 
void output(struct POINT* saske, int n)
{
    printf("%f", saske[n].x);
    printf("%f", saske[n].y);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include <stdlib.h>` вы пропустили здесь случайно, или намеренно? Если ее нет и в исходном вашем коде - вот и причина...

Вероятно, компилируете как 64-разрядное приложение. Без объявления `malloc` компилятор считает, что функция возвращает `int` и обрезает указатель до 32 битов...

Добавьте `#include <stdlib.h>` в вашу программу, и обращайте внимание на все предупреждения. Например, на

> warning C4013: malloc: нет определения; предполагается "extern" с возвратом типа "int"

> warning C4312: приведение типов: преобразование из "int" в "POINT *" большего размера

которые выдает Visual C++.

Comment: Точно. Я и забыл, что для функций -lloc нужна библиотека stdlib.h.